# Search an entire workbook with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, search

I have a part database that I need to search through to find whatever is searched for. I created a search page that gives the options to search specific columns or search in every column. It then prints the information that it finds out on the search page. I have the search via column part done, but I am struggling with the search all part. I keep getting an error 1004 at the line "AddressArray(j) = Sheets(i).Range(searchColumn & j + 1).Value". I assume that it has something to do with that line is looking to only search columns and not an entire workbook, but I don't know how to fix it.

Here is the code

```
Sub FindAll()

Range("B19:J1500") = ""

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim k As Integer, EndPasteLoopa As Integer
    Dim myText As String, searchRange As String
    Dim totalValues As Long
    Dim nextCell As Range

    k = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    myText = ComboBox1.Value
    Set nextCell = Range("B20")
    If myText = "" Then
        MsgBox "No Address Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Select Case ComboBox2.Value
        Case "SEARCH ALL"
            searchRange = Columns("A:J")
    End Select

    For i = 2 To k
        totalValues = Sheets(i).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim AddressArray(totalValues) As String

        For j = 0 To totalValues
            AddressArray(j) = Sheets(i).Range(searchRange & j + 1).Value
        Next j

        For j = 0 To totalValues
            If InStr(1, AddressArray(j), myText) > 0 Then
                EndPasteLoop = 1
                If (Sheets(i).Range(searchRange & j + 2).Value = "") Then EndPasteLoop = Sheets(i).Range(searchRange & j + 1).End(xlDown).Row - j - 1
                For r = 1 To EndPasteLoop
                    Range(nextCell, nextCell.Offset(0, 8)).Value = Sheets(i).Range("A" & j + r, "I" & j + r).Value
                    Set nextCell = nextCell.Offset(1, 0)
                Next r
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Debug.Print tc
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Before that line, you never give `searchColumn` a value, so it doesn't have a value for that.  Also, what kind of range are you searching? You may need to do `...Range(searchColumn & ":" & j + 1).Value`, if `searchColumn` is going to be a letter, like `A`, `B`, etc...

Comment: You're after the `FindAll` functionality as built and described by Chip Pearson [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/FindAll.aspx) and also written about by Ron de Bruin [here](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win006.htm)

Comment: @BruceWayne I changed somethings around above. I meant to change anything that is "searchColumn" to "searchRange" because since I am searching the entire workbook, im not just searching a specific column on each page. I don't know if this will change your answer or not. I also am now having a "Type mismatch" error at "searchRange = Columns("A:J")".

Comment: @CalebSutton doing `searchRange` as a string mainly complicates things...first you would just want `searchRange = "A:J"`. ...but even still `...Range(searchRange & j + 2)` doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 1):

this is something quick and dirty that will describe how to easily search all

```
 this = ComboBox2.Value
 dim arr() as variant
 arr = thisworkbook.sheets("yoursheet").usedrange
 for i = lbound(arr,1) to ubound(arr,1)
      for j = lbound(arr,2) to ubound(arr,2)
           if arr(i,j) = this then
                'code for found item
           end if
      next j
 next i
```

I know you are already kind of doing this, but I thought it was worth pointing out that it could be done in a much simpler fashion.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I recieved that solved my problem.

```
Sub FindOne()

    Range("B19:J5000") = ""

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim k As Integer, EndPasteLoopa As Integer, searchColumn As Integer, searchAllCount As Integer
    Dim myText As String
    Dim totalValues As Long
    Dim nextCell As Range
    Dim searchAllCheck As Boolean

    k = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    myText = ComboBox1.Value
    Set nextCell = Range("B20")
    If myText = "" Then
        MsgBox "No Address Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Select Case ComboBox2.Value
        Case "SEARCH ALL"
            searchAllCheck = True
        Case "EQUIPMENT NUMBER"
            searchColumn = 1
        Case "EQUIPMENT DESCRIPTION"
            searchColumn = 3
        Case "DUPONT NUMBER"
            searchColumn = 6
        Case "SAP NUMBER"
            searchColumn = 7
        Case "SSI NUMBER"
            searchColumn = 8
        Case "PART DESCRIPTION"
            searchColumn = 9
        Case ""
            MsgBox "Please select a value for what you are searching by."
    End Select

    For I = 2 To k
        totalValues = Sheets(I).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim AddressArray(totalValues) As String

        If searchAllCheck Then
            searchAllCount = 5
            searchColumn = 1
        Else
            searchAllCount = 0
        End If

        For qwerty = 0 To searchAllCount
            If searchAllCount Then
                Select Case qwerty
                    Case "1"
                        searchColumn = 3
                    Case "2"
                        searchColumn = 6
                    Case "3"
                        searchColumn = 7
                    Case "4"
                        searchColumn = 8
                    Case "5"
                        searchColumn = 9
                End Select
            End If

            For j = 0 To totalValues
                AddressArray(j) = Sheets(I).Cells(j + 1, searchColumn).Value
            Next j

            For j = 0 To totalValues
                If InStr(1, AddressArray(j), myText) > 0 Then
                    EndPasteLoop = 1
                    If (Sheets(I).Cells(j + 2, searchColumn).Value = "") Then EndPasteLoop = Sheets(I).Cells(j + 1, searchColumn).End(xlDown).Row - j - 1
                    For r = 1 To EndPasteLoop
                        Range(nextCell, nextCell.Offset(0, 8)).Value = Sheets(I).Range("A" & j + r, "I" & j + r).Value
                        Set nextCell = nextCell.Offset(1, 0)
                    Next r
                End If
            Next j
        Next qwerty
    Next I
    Debug.Print tc
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```